# Xcode 13 problemas para ver las imagenes

Tags: imagen, xcode, background

Porque motivo no veo las imagenes que estan, el background las tapa, no me pasada cuando las fui agregando, las vi asi cuando use el simulador y despues ya quedaron asi.
Aclaro que son principiante.
Saludos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La imagen DiceSix la tienes en los Assets? No la veo en Xcode. Si quitas el background verde si te aparecen las imágenes?

Comment: Hola gracias por responder!!! La solución estaba en subir el background por debajo de Safe Area, ósea por arriba de las imágenes. Así se resolvió. Soy principiante en esto. Saludos